# Global HashMap - Drools

Tags: hashmap, drools

Can someone let me know if it's possible to use global hashMap in drl file?

I am trying to implement a counter functionality to keep track of all the documents processed.

I want to declare the variable at rule file level (something like class variable in java).

Answer (score 2):

I have used global Lists without any problem, so I'd guess Maps would work just as well.

You can pass the global to the Working Memory when you're starting it with `setGlobal()` method. Then in your drl files you'll declare its use with the `global` keyword, like this

```
import java.util.Map

global Map myMap

when
  // some condition
then
  myMap.put(...);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you create a global variable in the main program,

```
public static HashMap<String , String> collectRule = new HashMap<String , String>();
```

then pass that variable into workingmemory,

```
WorkingMemory workingMemory = ruleBase.newStatefulSession();
workingMemory.setGlobal( "myGlobalList", collectRule );
```

Now go into .drl file,

```
    import java.util.Map
    global java.util.Map myGlobalList;
rule " Rule 1: Hello World"
    when 
        //some codition 
    then
        myGlobalList.put(key,value);
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

See the below example to use HashMap in drl file as global:

```
global java.util.HashMap gifts;
rule "Platinum Customer"    
    when
        $c: Customer(customerType == CustomerType.Platinum, discountUsed == false)
    then        
        modify($c){setDiscountUsed(true)} 
        PlatinumGift pg = new PlatinumGift($c);
        insert(pg);
        ArrayList cList = (ArrayList)gifts.get(CustomerType.Platinum); //You need to do explicit type casting here; Without this, Drools compiler thinks it is an Object 
        cList.add($c);

end

Java code to Invoke the above:

Map<CustomerType, ArrayList<Customer>> gifts = new HashMap<>();
gifts.put(CustomerType.Platinum, new ArrayList<Customer>());
        gifts.put(CustomerType.Gold, new ArrayList<Customer>());
        gifts.put(CustomerType.Silver, new ArrayList<Customer>());
        kieSession.setGlobal("gifts", gifts);
```